# Inconsistency in Mathematica of whether integral diverges or not?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider the following (beta function) integral

```
Integrate[(1 - x)^a x^b, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[(Gamma[1 + a] Gamma[1 + b])/Gamma[2 + a + b], Re[b]>-1&&Re[a]>-1]

The above general case states that the integral only converges when `Re[b]>-1` and `Re[a]>-1`. However, if we plug the following explicit constants into the integral, we get:

```
Integrate[(1 - x)^(-(1/2) - 2 I) x^(-2 + 7 I), {x, 0, 1}]
```

> (Gamma[-1 + 7 I] Gamma[1/2 - 2 I])/Gamma[-(1/2) + 5 I]

In which case Mathematica seems to return a perfectly finite result that is the same as the general result above, except the parameters have been chosen such that the general case would not converge.

Now I am a bit confused and would like to ask:

> Is the explicit result obtained above a bug in Mathematica and the integral actually should not converge at all?
>   Or maybe the result and convergence is fine, and the constraints in the general case are wrong?

Which one is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
Integrate[(1 - x)^(-(1/2) - 2 I) x^(-2 + 7 I), {x, m, 1}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[(Gamma[-1 + 7 I] Gamma[1/2 - 2 I])/
>     Gamma[-(1/2) + 5 I] + (1/50 + (7 I)/50) m^(-1 + 7 I)
>       Hypergeometric2F1[-1 + 7 I, 1/2 + 2 I, 7 I, m], 
>    0 < Re[m] < 1 && Im[m] == 0]

and note that the first term is the result from your second integral, while the second, [`Hypergeometric2F1`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1) term diverges for $m \to 0$ due to the factor $m^{(-1+7i)}$. So, the second example looks like a bug in [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate).

**Addendum**

Consider the [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) expansion about the origin:

```
Series[(1 - x)^a x^b, {x, 0, 1}] //TeXForm
```

> $x^b \left(1-a x+O\left(x^2\right)\right)$

So, the integral will only converge at the origin if $\Re(b)>-1$. Similarly, consider the [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) expansion about $x=1$:

```
Series[(1 - x)^a x^b, {x, 1, 1}] //TeXForm
```

> $(1-x)^a \left(1+b (x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)\right)$

This integral will converge at $x=1$ only if $\Re(a)>-1$.

Comment: To clarify: it's not the hypergeometric function that causes the divergence in the second term, it's the factor `m^(-1 + 7 I)`.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Agreed, my original wording was confusing.

Comment: The result is certainly confusing, but is it absolutely wrong in all cases?  With a suitable (non-standard) branch cut, I think you might be able to choose a spiral path (in the complex plane) to reach `x=0` without the integrand diverging.

Comment: Should I add the tag "bug" to the question?